# Does FOS Userbundle ignore db stored roles under certain conditions?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, role

After promoting a user for role ROLE_ADMIN via `php app/console fos:user:promote xyz ROLE_ADMIN` and `php app/console fos:user:promote xyz --super` the corresponding 'role' field in the database shows:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}
```

Both roles are added in `app/config/security.yml`, but after logging in as `xyz` I cannot access the desired page(403) and using the Symfonys toolbar the profiler/Security shows: `Roles [ROLE_USER]`.

The other bundle related tasks like logging in/out, register/confirm via email, reset password etc. work properly. How can I force the bundle (or Symfony?) to read the roles from db or why does it not read them?

my security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
```

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: article_index
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: article_index
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/article/new, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/article/create, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/comment/new, role: ROLE_USER }

acl:
    connection: default
```

Comment: Maybe try clearing the cache. Also you need to login again to get the desired role. If that wont help could you post your `security.yml`?

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I forgot to mention that I cleared cache via cache:clear and I logged in an out multiple times. I will post my security.yml soon

Comment: I have no idea why the roles are not read properly. Do you use the `dev` environment to log in? Maybe wrong database/user or something. Everything you posted here seems to add up correctly.

Comment: Yes, the complete application runs in dev env. Other user and db related tasks like logging in/out and access control via acl work properly - so I don't think, that it is the wrong db user. Thank you anyway